# Trying to install Atom. Unable to start Clangd language server

Tags: atom

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I am trying to set up Atom to write code with C++ and I get this:

```
Tried to spawn process using executable /usr/bin/clangd, which does not exist.
Ensure you have correctly configured the path to Clangd in the package settings.
```

and

```
This can occur if you do not have Clangd installed or if it is not in your path.
```

Can somebody explain to me in detail what should I do? I have clang and llvm installed by the terminal with
`sudo apt-get install`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/284351/195953

Answer (score 6):

This fixes the problem for me on Ubuntu 17.10:

```
sudo apt purge clang
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install clang-5.0
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-5.0 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-5.0 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clangd clangd /usr/bin/clangd-5.0 100
```

Comment: Note that you may have to install ```sudo apt-get install clang-tools-5.0``` on Ubuntu 16.04 before running ```sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clangd clangd /usr/bin/clangd-5.0 100```

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problem for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

> sudo mv /usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/clangd